# Android Studio rendering problems while New Project

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 and while lunching a new Project , it doesn't show any bar or Back-Button !
there is a small window  contains  rendering problems but it doesn't give any solutions ! 
Thank you !

[image]

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the newer versions in the gradle dependency are available.
- Update all dependencies.
- Try Refreshing the layout. If it doesn't work restart it. It won't disturb your layout on phone. It would be better if you could post the error.